# How to process double quotes in reged -- Scala

Tags: regex, scala

How to apply regex for double quotes in Scala?
My Actual String is (tomcat log file)

```
174.371.196.220 - - [07/Sep/2017:00:06:00 +0000] "GET /cs/v1/points/bal?memberId=2164699082&accountType=10 HTTP/1.1" 200
```

and my regex pattern is

```
(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})(\\D{1,6})(\\[.+?\\])( \".+?\")( \\d{1,3})
```

to find out IP, time, request and status code. This code working properly in java but when I am trying to apply same regex in scala on group 3 (( \".+?\")) its not able the find the match. I guess in scala representation will be different for double quotes. Can any one help me out on this....

In scala I am using pattern like this

```
val pattern = """(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(\D{1,6})(\[.+?\])( ["])( ".+?")( \d{1,3})""".r
```

mainly the group 3(double quotes request -( ".+?") ) is creating the problem. 
Any help will be highly appreciated...

Comment: Remove `( ["])`, it looks like the only difference.

Comment: See my full answer below with an example usage.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you introduced an extra `space`+`"` in the Scala pattern. Note that you needn't escape `"` inside a triple-quoted string literal, so there is no need to put it inside a character class, like in `["]`.

You may also put the space matching patterns outside the capturing groups to obtain clearer group values and you may use `\s*` to match even in cases where the whitespace is missing (`\s*` matches 0 or more whitespace chars).

See a [working Scala demo](https://ideone.com/1Cndys):

```
val pattern = """(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(\D{1,6})(\[.+?\])\s*(".+?")\s*(\d{1,3})""".r;
val input = """174.371.196.220 - - [07/Sep/2017:00:06:00 +0000] "GET /cs/v1/points/bal?memberId=2164699082&accountType=10 HTTP/1.1" 200""";
val res = input match {
    case pattern(ip, typ, time, request, status) => s"IP=$ip\nTime=$time\nRequest=$request\nStatus=$status"
    case _ => "NONE"
}
print(res)
```

Output:

```
IP=174.371.196.220
Time=[07/Sep/2017:00:06:00 +0000]
Request="GET /cs/v1/points/bal?memberId=2164699082&accountType=10 HTTP/1.1"
Status=200
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
"""(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(\D{1,6})(\[.+?\]) (".+?") (\d{1,3})"""
```

I've changed the following:

1. Removed ["] since you already look for the starting `"` in `(".+?")`
2. There was one too many spaces - I removed that
3. I don't include the spaces in the capture groups